# How to find the serial port in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, embedded, can-bus

I am using the `CANtact` toolkit for sending CAN message. The following code performs Denial of Service attack by sending a message with identifier 0 at a high rate

```
from canard import can

from canard.hw import cantact

dev = cantact.CantactDev("/dev/cu.usbmodem14511")

dev.start()

while True:

     print(dev.recv())
```

You will need to set the serial port (`/dev/cu.usbmodem14511` in this example) correctly.

How do I find the serial port of my laptop? I am using Ubuntu 18.04
[image: I Get the following output when is give ls/dev how to find my serial port from that?]

Comment: Take a look in your /dev directory perhaps ?

Comment: can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Um, type `ls /dev`, and you should see all your mapped devices, including one or more appropriately named serial ports.

Comment: I have attached screenshot of ls /dev how do i find my serial port from the list displayed?

Comment: Maybe these answers can help you: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88079/get-the-dev-tty-for-raspberry-pi/88083#88083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `/dev/ttyACM0`.
From the [wiki](https://wiki.linklayer.com/index.php/CANtact#Linux):

> On Linux, no driver is required. Depending on your Linux distribution, CANtact will either appear as /dev/ttyACM# or /dev/ttyUSB#. The # will depend on how many devices are connected.